# Can template specialisation be avoided in this case?

Tags: c++, templates

I recently came across the following:

```
// declare
template <class> struct A;
// specialise
template <template <class...> class C, class... Fields> struct A<C<Fields...>> {
  template <typename... Args> explicit A(C<Fields...>* c, Args&&... args) {}
};
// instantiate
template <template <class...> class C, class... Fields, class... Args>
A<C<Fields...>> MakeA(C<Fields...>* c, Args&&... args) {
  return A<C<Fields...>>(c, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

If I understand it correctly (comments above are mine), it is declaring `A` as a template, then specialising `A`, and the rest is more or less straightforward.

Why do we need to do this instead of being able to directly define the template, something like the following (which compiles and seems to be otherwise functional as far as I can tell):

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Fields> struct A1 {
 public:
  template <typename... Args> explicit A1(C<Fields...>* c, Args&&... args) {}
};

template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Fields, typename... Args>
A1<C, Fields...> MakeA1(C<Fields...>* c, Args&&... args) {
  return A1<C, Fields...>(c, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

My question is both approaches are equally valid/acceptable/technically correct?  If yes, is one preferable for some subtle technical or aesthetic reasons and why?

For additional context, I did not see any other specialisations in the original code so I'm not sure what the code with the specialisation buys us.

Comment: I think in first case A is forward declartion?

Comment: `A` and `A1` take different template parameters. If they are used, say, inside some template, you might not have that freedom of choice between them. Suppose you have a template with `T` and you need `A<T>`. How would you spell this type in terms of `A1`? When you have a specialization, a compiler will deduce some types, that you might not be able to provide explicitly (at least, in an easy way, without additional type traits).

Comment: @Evg: does this observation still apply if one only ever creates new instances of A1 using the `MakeA1()` method?

Comment: @giik It's hard to say without knowing what's inside `A`/`A1`. Sometimes `A` is beneficial, sometimes `A1`. If you face no technical difficulties/limitations with using both `A` and `A1`, use one that gives more readable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their usage syntax is different:

first snippet would be

```
A<std::vector<int>> a(&some_vector, 42, 51);
```

whereas the second would be

```
A<std::vector, int> a(&some_vector, 42, 51);
```

Which is indeed mitigated with `MakeA`.

But, difference might be important in template, where you would need to "propagate" the different signature:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T *t)
{
    A<T> a(t);
    // ...
}
```

versus

```
template <template <typename> class C,  typename... Ts>
void foo(C<Ts...> *t)
{
    A<C, Ts...> a(t);
    // ...
}
```

Additional caveat is for specialization and template aliases:

```
template <typename T>
using MyVec = std::vector<T>;
```

Whereas `MyVec<T>` is same as `std::vector<T>`, `MyVec` is not the same as `std::vector`

so

```
struct Specialization<A<std::vector<int>>> {/*..*/};
```

would be fine

whereas

```
struct Specialization<A<std::vector, int>> {/*..*/};
```

would be more problematic for `A<MyVec, int>`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  Indeed, I already run into this issue and it has convinced me that the former form (with speciaization) can be easier and more straightforward to use.